# Probability Inequality and exponent

Tags: probability-theory

I was not sure whether the following inequality holds.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are real-valued random variables. For any Borel set $A$ and any $\epsilon>0$,
\begin{equation}
P(X\in A) - P(Y\in A^\epsilon) \leq P(|X-Y|>\epsilon)
\end{equation}

Comment: Please include your efforts in proving/disproving the inequality.

Comment: Hint: if $X \in A$ and $Y \notin A^\epsilon$, then what can we say about $|X-Y|$?

Comment: Thanks both. I tried to apply Boole's inequality somehow, but couldn't figure out the way to proceed. I think what confuses me is $A^{\epsilon}$ as I find it a completely random quantity. My understanding is it can be randomly bigger or smaller than $A$ depending on what $A$ and $\epsilon$ are, so for example $[-1,2]^2 = [1,4]$ and $[0,2]^{0.5} = [0,\sqrt{2}]$. Perhaps this is where I am mistaken.